# SOAP request with PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

There is a webservice (WSDL) with a lot of functions. I want to call one of these functions with PHP.
The webservice provides a documentation wherein they put a format including header and xml, but I have no idea how I need to send the request from PHP. I searched for a couple of hours now, and I simply don't know.

An example request they provided:

```
POST POSTURL HTTP/1.1
Host: HOST
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "SOAPLOCATION"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Version xmlns="URL" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The response I should receive is also given, but I can't even send the request.

How do I send a request with PHP to get the response?
I tried some PHP SoapClient things, but I can't find a easy to read tutorial or some clear explanation...

If anyone can help me, that would be great!

Comment: have you looked here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Yes I looked at that, and I have no idea... I can create the SoapClient, then client->__getfunctions(), but I don't know how to call one of these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've an addition to the question:

The request is as following:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="...">
   <s:Body>
      <Search>
         <login>
            <Wholesaler>...</Wholesaler>
            <Username>...</Username>
            <Password>...</Password>
         </login>
         <itemRequests>
            <ItemRequest>
               <ArticleId>int</ArticleId>
               <SupplierId>int</SupplierId>
               <QuantityRequested>int</QuantityRequested>
            </ItemRequest>
         </itemRequests>
      </Search>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

There are two SoapHeaders I need to send:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: URI
```

I do know the service provider and the action identifier.

If I have the following variables

```
$service
$action
$request
$header
```

How can I send the request in PHP?
I tried

```
$client  = new SoapClient($service);
$result = $client->__doRequest($request, $service, $action);
```

But I do not receive a response it seems...

This is what the response should like:

```
Date: Thu, 09 Aug 2012 08:01:40 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 408
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8


<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SearchResponse xmlns="...">
      <SearchResult>
        <Wholesaler>...</Wholesaler>
        <Username>...</Username>
        <Error>false</Error>
        <DateTime>2012-08-09T10:01:40.39125+02:00</DateTime>
        <ItemResults />
      </SearchResult>
    </SearchResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

When I do a simple echo $result, the screen stays white and in the code there is no XML visible.

Comment: I fixed it... Did it with DOM

Answer (score 0):

Mapping some typical information may look something like this.

```
        $data = array(
        'UserName'  => $user->getUsername(),
        'Password'  => $user->getPassword(),
        'Email'     => $user->getEmail(),
        'FirstName' => $user->getFirstName(),
        'LastName'  => $user->getLastName(),
    );


    $response = $this->getDatasource()->TheServiceMethodForCreatingAUser(
        array(
             'user' => $data
        )
    );
```

The response is then handled however you wish (via an entity or response object of some description). The header must be done seperately by using new SoapHeader().

Hope this helps.